# How to schedule the launch of a specific website and action within that site at a given time on Mac?

Tags: macos

I'd like to launch a specific website (Focusmate.com) from my Mac every morning at a specific time. The site has a calendar that takes you to online meetings.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to launch the specific meeting that is scheduled for that day at the given time as well, but the only way that I can access the meetings, which are hosted in jisti.org, is first through my Focusmate calendar.

Is there anyone out there who knows how to automate this process so I essentially wake up to my meeting already launched and in progress?

I am using Chrome as the browser to this end on my Mac, OS 10.11.6), the two main sites are Focusmate (which contains the calendar) and then Jitsi.org which is the app that hosts the meeting when you click on 'launch session' from within the Focusmate calendar.

Please help!